# 504:Gateway Timeout in Web App using Docker

Tags: azure, docker, dockerfile, azure-web-app-service, azureportal

I am Deploying a web application When executing the app url its showing this error. In logs, displaying this error, "Waiting for response to warmup request for container". Please help me with this.

Building a Python Based App. Tried using Docker Container in Azure Portal.

Answer (score 0):

Try to increase the timeout on your webserver (e.g. nginx) or/and at python level, to allow your page to execute for longer.

You will receive a 504 error when the webserver waits too long for a page to be generated. The webserver closes the http request because it has reached a timeout.

Here some Nginx configurations to increase the timeout :

```
server {
    server_name _;
    root /var/www/html/public/;

    ###
    # increase timeouts to avoid 504 gateway timeouts, digits are seconds
    # for big files uploads
    ###
    client_max_body_size 0;
    proxy_send_timeout 3600;
    proxy_read_timeout 3600;
    fastcgi_send_timeout 3600;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 3600;
    
    # ... your config 
}
```

I'm not a Python developer but you may find some timeout configurations at Python level too (because there's a config in PHP to define the max_execution_time).